# How to get the variable names in a struct in swift?

Tags: swift

make an assumption:

```
struct A{ var a:String; var b:Int }
```

how can i make a for loop or some other ways to get the variables names in Struct A?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html

Comment: You would have to use reflection. But if you think you need to do this, think again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Mirror` is the class (it's actually a struct) for reflection in Swift. Below is a very simple example to enumerate your struct properties.

```swift
let a = A(a: "abc", b: 1)
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: a)
for child in mirror.children {
    print(child.label!)
    print(child.value)
}
```

And the output will be:

```
a
abc
b
1
```

Found a post on Swift Reflection API that's worth reading: https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/

Comment: Mirror is only suggested for Playgrounds and Debugging. It leaks memory if used in production unfortunately.

Comment: @aBikis While the doc says "Mirrors are used by playgrounds and the debugger.", it doesn't necessarily mean they can't be used in production. Personally I doubt that reflection would be noticeably slow for light usage.

Comment: I thought that as well! But it actually runs 3.5 X's slower! [link](https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/) Which isn't that big of deal but it actually created a significant number of memory leaks as well while using almost identical code to the code above. An issue that isn't documented by Apple but when used for instance as a protocol for many Structs to conform to, it ended up tanking my app.

Comment: @aBikis Thanks for sharing your experience! Totally agree we should not use it unless it's very light usage. Memory leaks of course is another big issue.